# Once I remove an attribute I cant add it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a select all checkbox but when I deselect it and select it again it just doesn't select the boxes anymore. While it does work at the first time.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="Everything">
    <input type="checkbox" id="all" />Select All
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="selectThese">
        <input type="checkbox" id="First" />First
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="Second" />Second
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Everything").on("click", "#all", function () {
        var carStatus = $("#all").is(':checked');
        if (carStatus == true) {
            $("#selectThese input").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectThese input").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Epsju/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use `prop()` for that, and since it accepts a boolean to check and uncheck the element, you can use your variable directly, or just ditch the variable and use `this.checked` :

```
$(function () {
    $("#Everything").on("change", "#all", function () {
        $("#selectThese input").prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Epsju/5/)

Comment: Wow thank you works like a charm and looks a lot shorter and better!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Epsju/6/

Use `change` also your fiddle uses `#car`, when it should use `#all`.

```
$(function () {
    $("#Everything").on("change", "#all", function () {
        $('#selectThese :checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hWQ4W/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#Everything").on("change", "#all", function () {
        $('#selectThese :checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

And viceversa

```
$('#selectThese :checkbox').on('change', function () {

            $('#all').prop('checked', $('#selectThese :checkbox:checked').length == $('#selectThese :checkbox').length)
        });
```